# Merge Sort, I/O using files shows Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mergesort

The following mergesort program written in C++ works without any error when the inputs are given through the console. But when I use text files to give the inputs, it gives me a segmentation error. I have tried printing messages at various parts of the code to check where is the mistake, but it isn't printing anything except d seg-fault message.
Here is the code. It works fine when I do not use files for giving the inputs/ displaying the output.

I ran this prog on a gcc compiler in a virtualbox 4.0.8(ubuntu OS) with a base memory of 1 GB. Cud the error be due to insufficient memory?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

int array[50];
int barray[50];

void merge(int p,int q, int r)
 {
    int i,j,k,l;
    l=p;
    i=p;
    j=q+1;

    while((i<=q)&&(j<=r))
    {

     if(array[i]<=array[j])
        barray[++k]=array[i++];

     else
        barray[k++]=array[j++];

    }

    if(i>q)
    {  
       for(l=j;l<=r;l++)
       { 
         barray[k]=array[l];
         k++;
       }
    }

   else
   {
      for(l=i;l<=q;l++)
      {
        barray[k]=array[l];
        k++;
      }

   }

   for(i=p;i<=r;i++)
        array[i]=barray[i];
}

void mergesort(int p, int r)
{
   int q;

   if(p<r)
      q=(p+r)/2;

   mergesort(p,q);
   mergesort(q+1,r);
   merge(p,q,r);

}


int main()
{
  int r, p, i;

  struct timeval tv1, tv2;/* For finding the running time */
  gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);

  ifstream fin;
  ofstream fout;

  fin.open("abc5.txt");
  fout.open("new5.txt");

  fin>>r;
  while(fin)
  {

    for(i=1;i<=r;++i)
    {
       fin>>array[i];
    }

  }

  mergesort(1,r);

  for(i=1;i<=r;++i)
  {
    fout<<array[i]<<"\n";
  }

  gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
  fout<<"Running Time: "<<(double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 + (double)    (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec)<<" sec";


 fin.close();
 fout.close();

 return 0;

}
```

*THE INPUT FILE*
8
3
6
2
8
9
1
4
10

Comment: May as well post the input file as well, since it *better not* be larger than 50 lines. If it is, that in conjunction with the improper 1-based vs. 0-based usage of C/C++ arrays is easily going to invoke UB.

Comment: Note: you never initialize `k` before using it as in index for dereference in your merge algorithm. That alone will invoke **undefined behavior**. Also, check your increment of `k` in the two primary assignments . Its not consistent and it needs to be. Honestly, the merge algorithm just needs a flat-out-rework.

Comment: Sry, had to eat lunch. Additionally, `q` can be uninitialized in your `mergsesort` algorithm if `(p<r)` is ever *false*; yet more undefined behavior. As I said, this needs a rework and better understanding of both undefined behavior and 0-based arrays. The algorithm to merge two segments from the same split array into temp storage, then copying back to the original is somewhat paramount to a merge sort algorithm. Said-merge algorithm needs to be *solid*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing leaves much to be desired. I will not be shy about telling you that, nor about saying simply that I would not do merge-sort this way. But it is what it is, so I'll cover it.

It is important to understand that sequence sorting using divide and conquer algorithms are all about passing some base reference within the sequence and some offsets from that reference. The algorithm should be independent of external variables (like `array[]` and `barray[]`) and take them as parameters instead. Further, remember you're programming in C++ (or C). Part of the beauty of *both* languages is their native pointer-arithmetic ability. It can be wonderfully used for algorithms like merge-sort. After I demonstrate how *your* merge and mergesort functions should work, I'll demonstrate what I'm talking about, then I'll proffer up the most-trivial merge sort you can do in C++ if you utilize the standard libraries functionality.

---

**Your Code First**

First a re-roll of your function using your parameters. I've taken the liberty of renaming the parameters to they're actually meaningful to the reviewer. The algorithm should be self-explanatory and I urge you to compare it side-by-side with what you were doing.

```
//  low  = starting index
//  mid  = middle index
//  high = last index
void merge(int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int i=low, j=mid, k=0;

    while (i < mid && j <=high)
    {
        if (array[i] < array[j])
            barray[k++] = array[i++];
        else
            barray[k++] = array[j++];
    }

    // finish whichever segment isn't done
    while (i < mid)
        barray[k++] = array[i++];
    while (j <= high)
        barray[k++] = array[j++];

    // copy back
    for (i=0;i<k;++i)
        array[low+i] = barray[i];
}

void mergesort(int low, int high)
{
    int len = high - low;
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    int mid = low + len/2;
    mergesort(low, mid);
    mergesort(mid, high);
    merge(low, mid, high);
}
```

Of note to this algorithm is the initial parameters passed *must* be valid indexes in the sequence. In other words, if you read an array of 8-elements, the *valid* indexes are `0..7` and therefore you would invoke it as `mergesort(0,7)`.

---

**A Different Approach**

The traditional merge sort in C/C++ uses an array base-index and length as its only parameters. The midpoint is calculated by the sort-algorithm. Though it is not strictly needed for the merge algorithm, (it too can just use length/2), it makes for a more robust algorithm on the off-chance you ever need merging from a segment that is not split right now the middle.

Don't get hung up on the usage of std::vector, std::random_device, etc below. They're used in the `main()` function solely to populate an array of random numbers that is then sorted, displayed both before and after the sort operation. What I want you to get out of this is the actual algorithm itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

void merge(int ar[], std::size_t mid, std::size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    // temporary storage. normally I use a RAII container
    //  such as std::vector<>, but I wanted to demonstrate
    //  the algorithm and indexing, not the memory management.
    //  none the less it is worth noting.
    int *tmp = new int[len];
    std::size_t i=0, j=mid, k=0;

    while (i < mid && j < len)
    {
        if (ar[i] < ar[j])
            tmp[k++] = ar[i++];
        else
            tmp[k++] = ar[j++];
    }

    // complete the unfinished segment
    while (i < mid)
        tmp[k++] = ar[i++];
    while (j < len)
        tmp[k++] = ar[j++];

    // and move back to the original array
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i)
        ar[i] = tmp[i];

    delete [] tmp;
}

void mergesort(int ar[], std::size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    // note pointer arithemtic in second call.
    mergesort(ar, len/2);
    mergesort(ar+len/2, len - len/2);
    merge(ar, len/2, len);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    data.reserve(20);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,50);

    // populate array
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data),
                data.capacity(),
                [&](){ return dist(rng);});

    // show on-screen
    for (auto n : data)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // mergesort
    mergesort(data.data(), data.size());

    // show on-screen
    for (auto n : data)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (varies)

```
15 10 8 38 20 21 9 43 8 22 19 45 12 16 17 36 2 32 6 37 
2 6 8 8 9 10 12 15 16 17 19 20 21 22 32 36 37 38 43 45
```

---

**The Part You'll Hate**

After going through all this work you'll be not-so-happy to know that two algorithms that do segment merging for you are already present in the standard library, namely [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) and [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge). Using one of those makes implementing `mergesort` *trivial*, as you'll see below:

```
#include <algorithm>

void mergesort(int ar[], std::size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    mergesort(ar, len/2);
    mergesort(ar+len/2, len-len/2);
    std::inplace_merge(ar, ar+len/2, ar+len);
}
```

Remember that if you ever need to use something besides `std::sort`, which honestly puts all of this to a point of near-uselessness besides fulfilling academic purpose.

Comment: It's probably related to a class assignment rather than him rolling out his own implementation.

Comment: @AlbertMyers I agree, and in such cases I don't jump on the "just use std::sort" bandwagon like so many others often do. That was the point of the three-part answer: (a) this is what's wrong with your code, (b) this is a different way, and (c) this is the least-work way. Someday hopefully the "I don't have to do that because its already in the lib" comfort will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

So given your input, it looks like when p=1 and r=1 that you use an uninitialized value for q in subsequent calls to mergesort.

The error you're receiving is because of unbounded recursion in the mergesort function.

Comment: i only tried it with only 8 elements, it doesn't work for that too.

Comment: What @WhozCraig said...can you post your input?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! But even after initializing q and k and changing indices to 0-based arrays, it is still showing seg-fault!

Comment: I think @WhozCraig has given your answer.  You should consider rewriting your algorithm.  That said, if you want to find out why *this* implementation is behaving the way it is, you might want to fire up GDB and step through it while it's running.  Learning to use gdb will pay dividends throughout your future career.